# Нужно ли освобождать (очищать) переменные, объявленные в функции?

Tags: delphi

Когда вызываешь функцию, нужно ли освобождать то что в ней создавал или функции делают все сами?

Например:

```
TPlayer = class

type
  TSomeType = class
    class function myFunc(str: string): TPlayer;
  end;

class function TSomeType.myFunc(str: string): TPlayer;
var
  Player: TPlayer;
begin
  Player.Param1 := 'qwer';
  Player.Param2 := 3;
  Player.Param3.SubParam1 := TStringList.Create;
  Player.Param3.SubParam1.DelimitedText := 'qwe,asd,zxc';
  Player.Param3.SubParam2 := False;
  Player.Param4. := TStringList.Create;
  Player.Param4.DelimitedText := 'rty,fgh,vbn';
  Result := Player;
end;

Player := TSomeType.myFunc(str);
```

Можно ли и нужно ли, после `Result := Player;`ставить `Player := nil;`?

Или надо каждый StringList по отдельности освобождать? Или и то и то?

Если из функции, вызвать еще одну и присвоить результат переменной, эту переменную тоже надо освобождать?

**UPD**

```
unit myTypes;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, ExtCtrls, IdContext,
  Generics.Collections, Generics.Defaults, SyncObjs, IdHashMessageDigest;
...

type
  TPlayer = class
    Name: String;
    Pass: String;
    Active: Boolean;
    Authorized: Boolean;
    Balance: Integer;
    Game: TPlayerGame;
    Oper: TPlayerParent;
    Admin: TPlayerParent;
    SuperAdmin: TPlayerParent;
    Session: String;
    TCPAddress: TIdContext;
    WSAddress: String;
    HttpAddress: String;
    HostWS: String;
    HostTcp: String;
    HostHttp: String;
    constructor Create(pName: String);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation
...

{ TPlayer }

constructor TPlayer.Create(pName: String);
begin
  //Inherited;
  self.Name := pName;
  self.Pass := '';
  self.Active := False;
  self.Authorized := False;
  self.Balance := 0;
  self.Game := TPlayerGame.Create;
  self.Oper := TPlayerParent.Create;
  self.Admin := TPlayerParent.Create;
  self.SuperAdmin := TPlayerParent.Create;
  Self.Session := '';
  self.TCPAddress := nil;
  self.WSAddress := '';
  self.HttpAddress := '';
  self.HostWS := '';
  self.HostTcp := '';
  self.HostHttp := '';

end;

destructor TPlayer.Destroy;
begin

  self.Game.Destroy;
  self.Oper.Destroy;
  self.Admin.Destroy;
  self.SuperAdmin.Destroy;
  self.TCPAddress := nil;
  Inherited;
end;

end.
```

Вот сценарии(я попытался описать вкратце поэтому не ищите логику в действиях):

```
function Authorizetion(login, pass): Boolean;
var
  Player: TPlayer;
begin
  // если авторизация удачна
  if Authorized then 
  begin
    // создаю объект
    Player := TPlayer.Create(login);
    // добавляю объект в список
    TmyServer.SetPlayer(Player.Name, Player); // TDictionary.AddOrSetValue
    // я создал Player , потом добавил в TDictionary его копию, 
    // а тот что в этой функцие, уничтожаю
    Player.Destroy;
  end;
end;

function LoadFromDateBase(name: String): TPlayer;
var
  Player: TPlayer;
begin
  // беру Player из TDictionary 
  Player := TmyServer.GetPlayer(pName);
  // меняю некоторые значения на прочтенные из базы
  Player := FDQuaery.FieldByName().AsString;
  Result := Player;
  // тут я сохранил Player в Result(тот объект который вызвал эту функцию), 
  // а теперь его уничтожаю
  Player.Destroy;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Когда вызываешь функцию, нужно ли освобождать то что в ней создавал или функции делают все сами?

**Правильно чётко разделять, кто отвечает за создание и удаление объектов.**

По идее, если ваша функция создает объект и отдает его вызывающей стороне, то теперь это обязанность вызывающей стороны - освободить этот объект.

В примере с вашей классовой функцией происходит непонятно что - вы не создаете объект, но работаете с ним. Инициализация вложенных объектов так же не должна быть на *этом* уровне.

Ниже ваш код и замечания/ошибки:

```
class function TSomeType.myFunc(str: string): TPlayer;
var
  Player: TPlayer;
begin
  // не создается объект Player!
  Player.Param1 := 'qwer';
  Player.Param2 := 3;
  // Объекты должны создаваться в конструкторах их владельцев
  // (SubParam1 должен создаваться внутри Player.Param3)
  Player.Param3.SubParam1 := TStringList.Create;
  Player.Param3.SubParam1.DelimitedText := 'qwe,asd,zxc';
  Player.Param3.SubParam2 := False;
  Player.Param4. := TStringList.Create; // Опечатка, лишняя точка
  Player.Param4.DelimitedText := 'rty,fgh,vbn';
  Result := Player;
end;
```

> Можно ли и нужно ли, после Result := Player;ставить Player := nil;?

Можно, но лишено смысла и не нужно. В переменной лежит только указатель на объект. Присвоение ему `nil` (или любого другого значения) никак ни на что не влияет. Исключение - интерфейсы (ISomething) и объекты на новых платформах с ARC. У них есть счетчики ссылок, но вам это пока использовать наверно не нужно.

> Или надо каждый StringList по отдельности освобождать? Или и то и то?

Каждый созданный объект надо освобождать - да. Иногда объекты регистрируются в неких структурах, тогда при выходе, структура сама освободит все объекты хранящиеся в ней (например Формы и их контролы сделаны так).

> Если из функции, вызвать еще одну и присвоить результат переменной, эту переменную тоже надо освобождать?

У вас каша:

- Переменные не надо освобождать. Освобождать надо созданные объекты.
- Не имеет смысла создавать объект и освобождать его в функции которая должна его возвращать.

---

> @Kromster я тоже так стараюсь делать, вот вопрос, создал объект, поработал с ним, положил в результат, объект уничтожил, в Result ничего не исчезнет? из-за того, что уничтожил объект, естественно после присвоения

Еще раз, в переменной лежит только адрес объекта. Адреса можно менять, присваивать, копировать, удалять. С самим объектом от этого ничего не происходит. Представьте, что объект это Вы. А переменная с адресом - это запись про вас в телефонной книге. Вы книгу можете ксерить, сжигать, перевыпускать, вырезать и вклеивать цифры. С вами от этого ничего не случится. Но .., если вас удалить, например, то запись в книге станет недействительна, как и во всех ее копиях.
Итого - если вы уничтожите объект, то все его "адреса" станут недействительны. Вы получите либо ошибку, либо мусорные данные ("звонит кто-то вам, а вас уже нет, и вместо вас отвечает черти кто")

> Кстати, пример не акти получился, на практике все грамотнее, там просто кода много

Усомнюсь. У вас отсутствуют базовые понятия о жизни объектов. Читайте статьи и книге по этой теме!

> Вот сценарии

Ошибка в том что вы вызываете `Player.Destroy;`. Вы положили в списки **копии указателей** на объект. Когда вы уничтожаете объект, получается, что в списке у вас указатели на **освобожденную память**, там будут данные объекта, пока их не перезапишет другим выделением памяти и получится мусор.

Comment: Более того, тут и переменная Player не нужна, можно работать сразу с Result: с точки зрения функции - это такая же переменная, как и Player.

Comment: @Alekcvp я придерживаюсь позиции одной точки возврата в таких случаях - то есть мы создали объект, поработали с ним, и потом положили его в результат.

Comment: @Kromster я тоже так стараюсь делать, вот вопрос, создал объект, поработал с ним, положил в результат, объект уничтожил, в Result ничего не исчезнет? из-за того, что уничтожил объект, естественно после присвоения

Comment: Кстати, пример не акти получился, на практике все грамотнее, там просто кода много

Comment: @Kromster дополнил вопрос

Comment: @ArtGrek13 дополнил ответ. Также, воздержитесь от копирования простыней кода в вопрос. Они там не к чему. Старайтесь всегда сделать **минимальный достаточный воспроизводимый пример**. Это не только ускорит прочтение вопроса, но и в большинстве случаев вы сами увидите ошибку, пока будете отсекать лишнее.

Comment: @Kromster спасибо за "в переменной лежит только адрес объекта", тему разжевали ниже с Igor, теперь все ясно. На счет простыней, учту. Одно маленькое уточнение, надеюсь правильно сформулирую. В объекте `Player: TPlayer;` есть переменная `TcpAddres: TidContext;`, в нее при подключении должна сохраняться ссылка на объект который создается TidTcpServerом, и мне уничтожая Player, не надо уничтожать TcpAddres, так как не я его создавал, а TcpServer сам его уничтожит. а с ссылкой в TcpAddres ничего делать не надо "Переменные не надо освобождать.". Это все верно?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 именно так :-) *и все же поищите/почитайте материалы про цикл жизни объектов. А также, возьмите за правило пользоваться `Free` вместо `Destroy`, а еще лучше `FreeAndNil()`.

Comment: @Kromster все таки в деструкторе TPlayerа следует поставить `TcpAddres := nil;` что бы удалить ссылку на не существующий объект TidContext который был удален, после разрыва соединения, в связи с чем я и удаляю TPlaeyr

Comment: @ArtGrek13 - только если Вам будет от этого легче :) - больше это ни на что не повлияет

Answer (score 1):

```
function LoadFromDateBase(name: String): TPlayer;
var
  Player: TPlayer;
begin
  // беру Player из TDictionary 
  Player := TmyServer.GetPlayer(pName);
  // меняю некоторые значения на прочтенные из базы
  Player := FDQuaery.FieldByName().AsString;
  Result := Player;
  // тут я сохранил Player в Result(тот объект который вызвал эту функцию), 
  // а теперь его уничтожаю
  Player.Destroy; // - ни в коем случае!!!
end;


// тут я сохранил Player в Result(тот объект который вызвал эту функцию),
```

Нет, Вы присвоили переменной `Result` значение, являющееся ссылкой (черт с ним, давайте уже скажем честно - "указателем") на объект типа `TPlayer`, на который уже указывала переменная `Player`.

Вы возвращаете ссылку на объект типа `TPlayer`, и тут же освобождаете память, которую этот объект занимает. В любой момент эта память может быть использована для чего-то другого, что перепишет останки Вашего бедного `TPlayer`а.

То же самое в `Authorizetion`.

```
  TPlayer = class
  private
    fName: String;
    fGame: TPlayerGame;
    fOper: TPlayerParent;
    fAdmin: TPlayerParent;
    fSuperAdmin: TPlayerParent;
    fTCPAddress: TIdContext;
  public
    Pass: String;
    Active: Boolean;
    Authorized: Boolean;
    Balance: Integer;
    Session: String;
    WSAddress: String;
    HttpAddress: String;
    HostWS: String;
    HostTcp: String;
    HostHttp: String;

    constructor Create(pName: String);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Name: String read fName;
    property Game: TPlayerGame read fGame;
    property Oper: TPlayerParent read fOper;
    property Admin: TPlayerParent read fAdmin;
    property SuperAdmin: TPlayerParent read fSuperAdmin;
    property TCPAddress: TIdContext read fTCPAddress write fTCPAddress;
  end;

constructor TPlayer.Create(pName: String);
begin
  Inherited Create;
  fName := pName;
  fGame := TPlayerGame.Create;
  fOper := TPlayerParent.Create;
  fAdmin := TPlayerParent.Create;
  fSuperAdmin := TPlayerParent.Create;
end;

destructor TPlayer.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(fGame);
  FreeAndNil(fOper);
  FreeAndNil(fAdmin);
  FreeAndNil(fSuperAdmin);
  fTCPAddress := nil;
  Inherited;
end;
```

В Delphi поля классов при создании объектов инициализируются значениями, соответствующими обнуленной памяти.

Свойства, у которых нет спецификатора `write`, предназначены только для чтения и не могут находится слева от оператор присвоения.

Значение имени игрока присваивается в конструкторе и, вроде бы, не меняется за время жизни объекта. Выведение его наружу как read-only свойства, позволяет отловить ошибочное присвоение ему нового значения наружным кодом на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61659/discussion-on-answer-by-igor------).